# How can I set minimum value and Max value to TextInput

Tags: react-native, textinput

As an example I want to give minimum value as 5000 and maximum value as 200000,In between those value user can type, if not in between user can't type.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example (https://snack.expo.dev/zlwWokoFK).

The way to do this is to to not let the text update if the length of the text is below or above the limits. In the `onChangeText` function.

Heres the code below

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {

  /* 
    Specify your upper and lower limits of length
  */
  const LOWER_LIMIT = 10;
  const HIGHER_LIMIT = 20;

  /* 
    State for the text
  */
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("ab".repeat(LOWER_LIMIT/2));

  /* 
    Function to update the text 
  */
  const onChangeText = (newText)=>{
    /* 
      If text is above or below length of limits then exit function
    */
    if (newText.length < LOWER_LIMIT || newText.length>HIGHER_LIMIT){
      return;
    }
    // Else update text
    setText(newText);
  }


  return (
    <View style={{
      flex:1,
      justifyContent:"center",
      }}>
        <TextInput
         onChangeText={value=>onChangeText(value)}
         multiline
         value={text}
         style={{
          height: 400,
          margin: 12,
          borderWidth: 1,
          padding: 10,
        }}
        />
    </View>
  );
}
```